# Unable To Execute AWS CLI Inside Bash Script via Jenkinsfile

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm unable to execute AWS CLI via Bash shell script called from a Jenkinsfile.

If the shell script is executed directly inside the Jenkins Docker, the scripts executes without issue, which suggests the assumed IAM role for the Jenkins Docker has the correct permissions.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue - in the Jenkinsfile it authorises the script to run via binding authorisation credentials to a certain IAM role, the IAM user assigned to the shell script was was not for the environment in which it was running!

```
withCredentials([[$class: 'AmazonWebServicesCredentialsBinding', 
credentialsId: 'jenkins-ci-aws-iam-user']]) {
```